# Ignored at new work place

Tags: new-job, new-hires

I completed 1 week at my new employer, a company with 5000+ people globally... and I'm being ignored.

During the first day I was given the office tour, offered a temporary workplace, presented some introduction courses, completed a few security tests, met the people manager and promised that I would meet the dev team starting next day. I never met the dev team until now (5th day).

I sent a few emails to my people manager about this, but he never replied to them. I asked him personally and said we'll talk later as he is too busy at the moment (it happened twice :|). Also emailed my HR contact, but she never replied either, and I'm not sure where to physically meet her.

I don't know how to continue from here, at my first two jobs I met the team during my first day, and things proceeded normally from there. Here I'm given a temporary desk in the training room with a laptop... and being completely ignored.

Comment: Your manager said he is busy and he would talk later, so what is the problem you are with that? Every job is different, you shouldn't measure a job by the yardstick of the old one. It is not clear what your goal is here.

Comment: I'm used to "later" being somewhere in the next 24h, not a week, two or undefined later.

Comment: I admit that at my previous jobs things happened with more celerity, perhaps I am being impatient, but in my experience being ignored as a new joiner for 5 days is not the norm, hence this stackexchange message.

Comment: Is your concern about being seen as unproductive or about being bored with nothing to do?

Comment: My concern is that companies usually hire new people because their skills are needed. With that in mind, I don't know what to make of current circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

People are busy. Do not take it personally.

They may have be unprepared and therefore hence the initial problems.

See what happens in week three.

Answer (score 8):

Just keep pushing. Why not get up and go looking for the dev team? Chances are they haven't found a desk for you yet. But 5 days is a long time to be sitting on your hands.

I'd go find the team and introduce myself if nothing else and see what happens from there. They may have some tasks you can work on either there or in the training room.

Comment: Taking the initiative to go looking for work gets the OP off to a good start. Do be prepared for the possibility that the team are also busy. There may be some emergency that came up after they had committed to the start date.

Comment: Can't hurt, it's not like he has something else to do.

Comment: I tried, with little success as I don't know the actual team members, floor or even project specifics that might help other colleagues point me in the right direction. And the guardians of this information can't seem to find the time to share this knowledge with me.

Comment: You can't check the whole place in 5 days, must be pretty big, usually you just ask reception where the IT division is located.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't unusual.  I've seen places where someone gets hired for a job requiring a computer, but IT doesn't get things settled for weeks and weeks.  Find yourself something halfway related to your position to keep busy with.  Don't drive yourself nuts.  Being idle isn't going to be an issue until you actually receive some assignments.

Answer (score 1):

The chances that any of that reflects in *you* is slim to none. They were busy before you got there and evidently they are still busy.